# Program to keep track number of login attempts

Tags: login, logs, authentication

Is there any way to keep track of number of attempts made by a user to login into his system?

Answer (score 3):

On linux, logins and failed logins are logged in binary format in /var/log/wtmp and /var/log/btmp respectively.  In order to view those logs in human readable format, you need to use the command `last` or `lastb`.  You can also check your /var/log/auth.log (which is plain text) for successful / failed authentication attempts.

In OpenBSD there is no /var/log/btmp, but the last command works.  Also, the authlog is in /var/log/authlog.

In Solaris the last command works, but (at least on the system I have access to) authlog seems to be empty.

Comment: Thank you very much.... Is it possible to run a program before user login?. Not like startup programs but those likely to be run once after user login.

Comment: On my system, Debian squeeze, both /var/log/wtmp and /var/log/btmp are binary files.

Comment: Yeah those are binary files. So how will you know how many failed attempts are made before an successful login.

Comment: @Winbros: `last` and `lastb` produce a human readable output from `wtmp` and `btmp` respectively. In debian, `/var/log/auth.log` logs every login attempt, failed or successful.

Comment: @forcefsck Ok let me check

Comment: @Faheem-Mitha Yes, that's why you need to use last, or lastb to read them... this wasn't very clear in my answer, so I've edited it to make it a bit more clear.